# How can I list my app for download files?

Tags: android, browser, download

I want to download files from browser through my application. I am trying to list my app in `complete action using` dialog. It shows for other action like view files, etc but in case of download files it doesn't show in dialog. how can i list my app like in the image?

I have used these filters in my activity

```
<intent-filter> <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" /> <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/> <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE"/> <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/> <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
```

[image: example image]

Comment: @Nilesh, how to do this using intent-filter?

Answer (score 1):

I have done this by adding these filters and now it's working for all cases.

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.APP_BROWSER"/>
            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.NOTIFICATION_PREFERENCES"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data
                android:scheme="googlechrome"/>
            <data
                android:scheme="http"/>
            <data
                android:scheme="https"/>
            <data
                android:scheme="about"/>
            <data
                android:scheme="javascript"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data
                android:scheme="googlechrome"/>
            <data
                android:scheme="http"/>
            <data
                android:scheme="https"/>
            <data
                android:scheme="about"/>
            <data
                android:scheme="content"/>
            <data
                android:scheme="javascript"/>
            <data
                android:mimeType="text/html"/>
            <data
                android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
            <data
                android:mimeType="application/xhtml+xml"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data
                android:mimeType="multipart/related"
                android:scheme="file"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_SEARCH"/>
            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.speech.action.VOICE_SEARCH_RESULTS"/>
            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter
            android:priority="-101">
            <action
                android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data
                android:scheme="http"/>
            <data
                android:scheme="https"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="com.sec.android.airview.HOVER"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

add these two tags inside your `<intent-filter>` tag

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
```

Comment: @Umesh Aawte , this will list your app in dialog

Answer (score 0):

add this code in your `manifest` inside your `launcher activity` tag.

```
  <activity
    android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    </intent-filter>

    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

    </activity>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try downloading the files using the API http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html