# How to show my app as a downloader

Tags: android, deep-linking

How can i register my app as a downloader as shown in the screenshot below. I have tried adding below code in my manifest but didn't work.

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent-filter>
```

[image]

here is my activity in manifest:

```
        <activity
        android:name=".modules.downloader.home.HomeActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

Comment: have you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38175930/handle-download-intents-in-my-app

Comment: may be this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30611898/how-can-i-list-my-app-for-download-files

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i tried but my app is still not showing in the chooser :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide MIME type as well.  If you support all types of files, then you can give `<data android:mimeType="*/*" />`

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data android:mimeType="*/*" android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:mimeType="*/*" android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: i tried your solution but my app is not getting listed in the chooser :(

Comment: @ZubairRehman: Could you share the full manifest please?  I assume you have the launcher intent already.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760276/android-intent-filter-associate-app-with-file-extension - please check the second answer from here.  it is specific to mapping certain file extension but you can use wild card to make it applicable for all.

Comment: i have updated my question, please have a look at the manifest. even i tried supporting images only but still its not working